# How to retrieve an ID of the selected item in a dynamic Spinner?

Tags: android, sqlite, object, spinner

I have a spinner which is populated with `Category` objects that are retrieved from the db. The Categories table has `_id` and `category_name` columns. I want to show the category name in the spinner, but when the user selects an item, I need it to retrieve the selected item's ID. I tried the following:

Declaring variables (in class level):

```
int currCategoryId;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

NotesManager manager = new NotesManager(this);
ArrayList<Category> arrListCategories; 
ArrayList<String> arrListCategoriesString = new ArrayList<String>();

Spinner spCategories;
```

Instantiating them in `onCreate` method:

```
manager.getAllCategories();
    arrListCategories = manager.getAllCategories();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrListCategories.size(); i++) 
    {
        Category currCategory = arrListCategories.get(i);
        arrListCategoriesString.add(currCategory.getCategory_name().toString());            
    }

    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrListCategoriesString);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
    spCategories.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
```

And this is the spinnerListener I tried:

```
OnItemSelectedListener spinnerListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() 
    {       
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                int pos, long id) {
            // An item was selected.
            //currCategory = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(); 
            //selectedCategory = 
            Category selectedCategory = (Category)spCategories.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            currCategoryId = selectedCategory.getId();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {    

        }                   
    };
```

But in this case the app crashes and I'm getting a "

> String cannot be cast to Category" at this line: `Category
>   selectedCategory = (Category)spCategories.getItemAtPosition(pos);`

I also tried this:

```
currCategoryId = view.getId();
```

But then instead of 1 or 2 (depending on what category I selected, currently I have 2 of them), I'm getting a very long number...

How can I fix it? How can I retrieve the ID of the selected object?

Comment: try parent.getAdapter.getItem(); and cast this item to your desired class, I hope this will work

Comment: @AdeelPervaiz Nope, didn't work - there's no getAdapter method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `ArrayAdapter` anyway because it's for Strings only (not Categories). Hence why you're getting a casting exception. Since you have your Category `ArrayList` and your String `ArrayList` (which is used for the `ArrayAdapter`) in the same order, just use

```
Category selectedCategory = arrListCategories.get(pos);
```

in your `onItemSelected()` method

Comment: Yes, it worked! I tried to use this line: `Category selectedCategory = (Category) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);`, but obviously that didn't work. I see my mistake now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

I would use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` because it stores multiple columns, instead of an `ArrayAdapter` that only stores one.

**First** change `NotesManager.getAllCategories()` to return a `Cursor` that uses:

```
"SELECT _id, category_name FROM Table;"
```

You could alphabetize the results if you want:

```
"SELECT _id, category_name FROM Table ORDER BY category_name;"
```

**Next** bind this `Cursor` straight to your Spinner:

```
Cursor cursor = manager.getAllCategories();
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, new String[] {"category_name"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spCategories.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Finally** in your `OnItemSelectedListener` everything is ready and waiting:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    // The parameter id already refers to your Category table's id column, 
}
```

No extra *`get()` calls* or *converting* Cursors into Lists necessary!